# Error: Unable to resolve image URL from source (null)

Tags: reactjs, blogs, sanity

I am using Sanity and React to create a blog page. Everything seems to be okay but when you click on a blog to read more I get the error message "Error: Unable to resolve image URL from source (null)" What could be the issue? Below is part of my OnePage.js page where console shows there's an error

```
  </h2>
  <div className="flex justify-center text-gray-800">
   <img
    src={urlFor(postData.authorImage).url()}
     className="w-10 h-10 rounded-full"
      alt=""
   />
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks like `authorImage` in this case is `null`, meaning the author doesn't have an image. To prevent this from happening, you can check whether or not the author has an image before rendering the image tag. In other words, something like this:

```
  </h2>
  <div className="flex justify-center text-gray-800">
  {postData.authorImage && (
    <img
      src={urlFor(postData.authorImage).url()}
      className="w-10 h-10 rounded-full"
      alt=""
    />
  )}
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of passing it before the image element, you can pass the operator in the inside the src`

```js
  <div className="flex justify-center text-gray-800">
 
    <img
      src={urlFor(postData.authorImage && postData.authorImage ).url()}
      className="w-10 h-10 rounded-full"
      alt=""
    />
</div>
```

`

Answer (score 1):

I encountered the error but in my case it was (undefined)
I made a sanity blog post that had no image, therefore there was no image url to be found in sanity. Perhaps you can give it a fallback in case of a missing image.

```
src={postData.authorImage ? urlFor(postData.authorImage).url() : "fallback-image-url" }
```

If you're using next.js and you use a url, remember to add the cdn in next.config.js