# Trying to resolve error "urlForImage.ts:43 Uncaught Error: Unable to resolve image URL from source (undefined)" using Sanity and React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, sanity

I am running into an error using Sanity with Javascript and React. The app is a personal portfolio site and I have successfully pulled data from Sanity for 3 other sections. Now that I am working on the Testimonials section, I am trying to pull 2 images (jpegs) that currently loaded in Sanity Studio: testimonials > imgurl
In my return statement, I am checking for length of testimonials so that I only fetch if at least one is present. Inside the image tag, I am using `src={urlFor(testimonials[currentIndex].imgurl)}`

Code Block:

```
return (
<>
  {testimonials.length && (
    <>
      <div className="app__testimonial-item app__flex">
        <img src={urlFor(testimonials[currentIndex].imgurl)} alt="testimonial" />            
      </div>
    </>
  )}
</>
```

);

```
 1. urlFor is the function used to fetch images off Sanity, as per their documentation.
 2. currentIndex is the useState inside of the Testimonial function, which acts as the container component for this section of the website. It will keep track of the state of the image being displayed and will cycle through others with a clickable action (code not present here)


**Question:** I am getting an error that is caused by the img tag and cannot find anything online about a fix. This [thread][1] does not fix my issue. 


**ERROR MESSAGE**:
react-dom.development.js:20085 The above error occurred in the <img> component:
    at img
    at div
    at Testimonial (http://localhost:3000/main.20b2c7aaa42080546b80.hot-update.js:37:90)
    at div
    at VisualElementHandler (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:119980:38)
    at MotionComponent (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:119880:20)
    at HOC
    at div
    at div
    at HOC
    at div
    at App
Consider adding an error boundary to your tree to customize error handling behavior.
Visit https://reactjs.org/link/error-boundaries to learn more about error boundaries.


Error Message

Uncaught Error: Unable to resolve image URL from source (undefined)
    at urlForImage (urlForImage.ts:43:1)
    at ImageUrlBuilder.url (builder.ts:229:1)
    at ImageUrlBuilder.toString (builder.ts:234:1)
    at setValueForProperty (react-dom.development.js:672:1)
    at setInitialDOMProperties (react-dom.development.js:8931:1)
    at setInitialProperties (react-dom.development.js:9135:1)
    at finalizeInitialChildren (react-dom.development.js:10201:1)
    at completeWork (react-dom.development.js:19470:1)
    at completeUnitOfWork (react-dom.development.js:22815:1)
    at performUnitOfWork (react-dom.development.js:22787:1)


  [1]: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69031649/error-unable-to-resolve-image-url-from-source-null
```

Answer (score 0):

Go to Your testimonial file in schema  and change this section:

```
    {
        name:'imgurl',
        title:'ImgUrl',
        type: 'image',
        options: {
          hotspot: true,
    },
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use this instead - will work for you

```
{Data.image && (<img src={urlFor(Data.image.url()} alt="testimonial" />)}
```

Instead of using imgurl or use url().
Also I don't understand why you're using [currentIndex]. but ya anyway..